# Callback is not a function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement classMethods of a sequelize model for authentication.

```
authenticate: function(password, callback) { // authenticate a given login body
            bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null, isMatch);
            });
        },
```

When I try to run the above codes, the command said "callback is not a function".

Comment: `callback` is an argument to the function, and you haven't shown us what value you are passing to it. Clearly you aren't passing the correct value to it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling authenticate? Make sure when you write your callback as a parameter you don't use parentheses. So make sure you do 'authenticate(foo,bar)' instead of authenticate(foo,bar())'

Comment: Seems to be more of a comment than an answer.